# How to check element of list 1 not in list 2

Tags: python

Python n00b here , trying to print elements from subsFile which are not in clisFile.
I am however getting some unexpected results.

Running on Python 2.6.6.

I get the feeling I am missing something essential here but I cannot put my finger on it.

When running:

```
import csv

clisFile=open('cli.csv', 'rb')
clis=csv.reader(clisFile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

subsFile=open('subsToBeCleaned.csv', 'rb')
subs=csv.reader(subsFile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

for sub in subs:
        #if sub in clis:
        print(sub)

print "----"

for cli in clis:
        print(cli)
```

I get

```
['xxxx5201727']
['xxxx181000']
['xxxx5205685']
----
['xxxx181000']
['xxxx181001']
['xxxx181002']
['xxxx181003']
['xxxx181004']
```

However :

```
import csv

clisFile=open('cli.csv', 'rb')
clis=csv.reader(clisFile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

subsFile=open('subsToBeCleaned.csv', 'rb')
subs=csv.reader(subsFile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

for sub in subs:
        if sub in clis:
                print(sub)

print "----"

for cli in clis:
        print(cli)
```

outputs

```
----
```

File Contents:

```
# cat cli.csv
xxxx181000
xxxx181001
xxxx181002
xxxx181003
xxxx181004

# cat subsToBeCleaned.csv
xxxx5201727
xxxx181000
xxxx5205685
```

Comment: Note that Python 2 reached end of life almost 3 years ago (and that was Python 2.7 then). You should not use it anymore, unless you're stuck with some old code. Use Python 3.

Comment: The server where I am working with this is running rhel 6.3 so kinds stuck with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the "`if sub in clis`" statement to an "`if set(sub) == set(cli)`" statement

Answer (score 1):

At an initial look the the problem according to your print statement seems that individual sub is also an array so

`if sub in clis` is not giving you expected .

Your solution:

```
for sub in subs:
    for cli in clis:
        if sub[0] in cli:
            print(sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, you got me on the right track.
I was unfortunately trying to compare apples to oranges as clis was not a list but rather a _csv.reader object ( found out when trying to print it ).

```
xxxx5201727
<_csv.reader object at 0x7fdcf4d87130>
xxxx181000
<_csv.reader object at 0x7fdcf4d87130>
xxxx5205685
<_csv.reader object at 0x7fdcf4d87130>
```

The following gets the job done ( for my purposes ):

```
import csv

cliList=[]
subList=[]

clisFile=open('cli.csv', 'rb')
clis=csv.reader(clisFile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

subsFile=open('subsToBeCleaned.csv', 'rb')
subs=csv.reader(subsFile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

for cli in clis:
        cliList.append(cli)

for sub in subs:
        subList.append(sub)

for sub in subList:
        if sub in cliList:
                print(''.join(sub))
```